# Using a Calculation within a JOIN or after using a CTE performance

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, optimization, sql-optimization

I have tried Googling this to find out if there might be a clear answer on this but I am currently trying to evaluate some ways to optimize a query for work with a connection to MS SQL Server.

The current query has a join that looks something like:

```
..
SELECT
column1
, column2
, column3
INTO #temptable1
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1

WITH cte1 as (
SELECT c1.*
CASE WHEN ((t1.CALENDAR_YEAR%4 = 0 and t1.CALENDAR_YEAR%100<>0) or t1.CALENDAR_YEAR%400=0) AND MONTH(t1.START_DATE)=2 AND DAY(t1.START_DATE)<=29 AND DAY(t1.END_DATE)>=29 THEN (DATEDIFF(day,t1.START_DATE,t1.END_DATE)+1-1)/365.00
ELSE (DATEDIFF(day,t1.START_DATE,t1.END_DATE)+1)/365.00
END AS datecalc
FROM temptable#1 as c1
)

SELECT 
column1
, column2
, datecalc
FROM cte1
```

My thinking is to simply move the datecalc up into the SELECT INTO query and do away with the CTE all together because the calculation can be added to the rows as they are joined, rather than executing the join AND THEN going back through every row to add the calculation as follows:

```
..
SELECT
column1
, column2
, column3
CASE WHEN ((t1.CALENDAR_YEAR%4 = 0 and t1.CALENDAR_YEAR%100<>0) or t1.CALENDAR_YEAR%400=0) AND MONTH(t1.START_DATE)=2 AND DAY(t1.START_DATE)<=29 AND DAY(t1.END_DATE)>=29 THEN (DATEDIFF(day,t1.START_DATE,t1.END_DATE)+1-1)/365.00
ELSE (DATEDIFF(day,t1.START_DATE,t1.END_DATE)+1)/365.00
END AS datecalc
INTO #temptable1
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1

SELECT 
column1
, column2
, datecalc
FROM #temptable1
```

Any thoughts on performance here? Currently the script takes 5 hours to run (there is a lot more than just this but this seems to be the pain area of the script) and the main table has 174 Million records for reference.

Comment: Tag the database you are using. Confusingly you mention SSMS (SQL Server) and Postgres - your syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: The `case` expression will be negligible - granted this is a contrived example but what is the purpose of using a temp table to only select all rows from it? You have no filtering criteria so you are reading all rows from table1; if column1 in both tables were clustered SQL Server could use a `merge` join which might be the best you are going to get. And SQL 2008...?

Comment: @Stu Thanks I have updated the tags. And those were my thoughts exactly. I didn't understand why they would need to create the temp table to reference all of the columns again just to add a calculation afterwards. But I was wondering if by moving this into the temp table to begin with would the time to run the query actually be affected greatly?